# Get an Array of Specific Value from the Json Model in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, model

I want an array which contains only the **userName** from my following *Model Class*:

```
struct MyModel: Codable {
    let status: Int?
    let message: String?
    let data: [MyModelClass]?
}

struct MyModelClass: Codable {
    let userID, userName, email, emailCode: String?
    let phone, password: String?
    let image: String?
    let dreamInfo: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id"
        case userName = "user_name"
        case email
        case emailCode = "email_code"
        case phone, password, image
        case dreamInfo = "dream_info"
    }
}
```

I want an array which has only **userNames**. How to do it in swift?

My model responses like this:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "user found ",
    "data": [
        {
            "user_id": "1",
            "user_name": "ali",
            "email": "ali@gmail.com",
            "email_code": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
            "image": "",
            "dream_info": "this is my dream"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "2",
            "user_name": "raza",
            "email": "raza@gmail.com",
            "email_code": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
            "image": "",
            "dream_info": "this is my dream"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "3",
            "user_name": "usman",
            "email": "usman@gmail.com",
            "email_code": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
            "image": "",
            "dream_info": "this is my dream"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "4",
            "user_name": "haroon",
            "email": "haroon@gmail.com",
            "email_code": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
            "image": "",
            "dream_info": "this is my dream"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want only the User Names from this model. This is my desired output:

> var myArray = ["ali", "raza", "usman", "haroon"]

If there are 10 values in the model class then I need *myArray* to have all the 10 user names.

Comment: You can iterate with a for loop, or use a hight method like `map()`. What have you tried? Note that doing a manual for loop isn't bad, it's basic algorithm, and will help you with your coding skills later. A `map` is more "Swifty" and higher level methods, but if you don't understand why it works, it might not be relevant to your current level.

Comment: Use:
`var arr: [MyModelClass] = []
for item in data where item.userName == "raj" {
    arr.append(item)
}
debugPrint(arr)`

Comment: @Larme I was searching regarding this and came across the solution with **map()** but was not understanding how to implement it.

Comment: @TaimoorArif `map()` will not work here unfortunately bcz it return whole array but you need filtered one.

Comment: @Kudos I need an array which contains only userNames like this: `[ { "userName" , "ali" },  { "userName" , "usman" },  { "userName" , "raza" }] `

Comment: Oh, I didn't understood you wanted to keep only the values that match `userName`, so it's `filter`, not `map` indeed. Giving a sample of input/parameters/desired output might have made clearer.

Comment: @Larme I had updated my question now check it

Comment: @TaimoorArif Please check my answer... This is best and optimised way . By here you will get other properties too like.

Comment: You would make things easier for yourself by _not_ declaring everything optional and it is also a bad habit since it might hide decoding issues with your code.

Comment: What you want is `let userNames = myModel.data?.compactMap(\.userName)` or if you made your properties non-optional `let userNames = result.data.map(\.userName)`

Comment: you just use map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working code, tested in playground

```
import Foundation

let json: String = """
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "user found ",
    "data": [
        {
            "user_id": "1",
            "user_name": "ali",
            "email": "ali@gmail.com",
            "email_code": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
            "image": "",
            "dream_info": "this is my dream"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "2",
            "user_name": "raza",
            "email": "raza@gmail.com",
            "email_code": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
            "image": "",
            "dream_info": "this is my dream"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "3",
            "user_name": "usman",
            "email": "usman@gmail.com",
            "email_code": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
            "image": "",
            "dream_info": "this is my dream"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "4",
            "user_name": "haroon",
            "email": "haroon@gmail.com",
            "email_code": "0",
            "phone": "0",
            "password": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
            "image": "",
            "dream_info": "this is my dream"
        }
    ]
}
"""

struct MyModel: Codable {
    let status: Int?
    let message: String?
    let data: [MyModelClass]?
}

struct MyModelClass: Codable {
    let userID, userName, email, emailCode: String?
    let phone, password: String?
    let image: String?
    let dreamInfo: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id"
        case userName = "user_name"
        case email
        case emailCode = "email_code"
        case phone, password, image
        case dreamInfo = "dream_info"
    }

}

func loadJson() {
    
    guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8) else {
        print("Cant convert String to Data")
        return
    }

    
    do {
        let model = try JSONDecoder().decode( MyModel.self, from: data)
        if let data = model.data {
            let array = data.filter({$0.userName != nil}).map({$0.userName!})
            print(array)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Can't convert json to model")
    }
    
}

loadJson()
```

Result in console:
[image]

Comment: thanks buddy but I got my answer in the comment section of my question

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification of the answer of Kudos

```
var arr = []
for item in data {
    arr.append(item.Username)
}
debugPrint(arr)
```

Comment: You are not getting it. I do not want the whole array, I just want the userNames in it

Comment: @TaimoorArif i have edited my answer, does this fix it?

Comment: I already got my answer in my above comments. thanks

Comment: Also this doesn't compile so it's not very useful

Comment: @Kudos you better understand the question first. I know how to write a for loop but I was not using that fetch the name where name = kudos, I wanted the whole array which has only names